# Getting started with Workflows in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-2010

I'm a starting sharepoint developer asked to implement the following scenario in sharepoint 2010.
We're a bit lost on the best approach to get started.. I'm really struggling to find the best practise solution.

**This is the requested flow:**

- A user can make a request with a title and a description.
- A mail gets sent to the representative with a link to a form.
- A representative can approve or reject the request.

  - If approved: A mail gets sent to Board with a link to form
  - If rejected: A mail gets sent to the user with the message that it has been rejected.
- when the request was approved by the representative, the board can approve or reject the request.
- A mail gets sent to the user and the representative with the descision of the board.

**So the list has the following fields:**

- Request title
- Request description
- Representative approval
- Representative description
- Board approval
- Board description

*The user should see the following form:*

- Request title (editable)
- Request description (editable)

*The representative should see the following form:*

- Request title (read-only)
- Request description  (read-only)
- Representative approval  (editable)
- Representative description  (editable)

*The Board should see the following form:*

- Request title (read-only)
- Request description (read-only)
- Representative approval (read-only)
- Representative description (read-only)
- Board approval (editable)
- Board description (editable)

***My questions:***

- What tool is most appropriate for making the forms? Infopath? SPD? VS2010? How do I handle rights to make sure only the board can access the board edit form?
- What kind of workflow do I use? When do I start the workflow(s)? What do I use to develop the workflow(s)?
- How do I handle rights when showing the listview with all requests?
- How can I build the links in the mails sent to the different groups.

Thanks in advance for **any** advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding some of your questions.... I am not 100% sure, but in the 2007 version, InfoPath was an enterprise function. So the use of InfoPath may be a function of the version you have (Foundation vs 2010 Enterprise).

SPD may be a good start for you, especially since you can now export your SPD developed workflows and import them into VS 2010 to update the functionality.

Regarding the board editing... Based on your security implementation (FBA vs AD) you probably want to do some kind of role check on the load of the edit form. I would probably start by having a ASPX form (not Infopath) that you can determine the type of user you have. Based on the user, you can display or not display appropriate fields and fire up event handlers to buttons as need be.

I would most likely start with a sequential workflow since you do not have numerous steps that need to be worried about. State Workflows are for more complex implementations.

Comment: we ended up using reusable workflows that are bound to a custom content type that we created for each list that we created for each group (requester/representative/board). Still following? :-) Going to accept this one as I won't get any other answers..

Comment: InfoPath Forms Services were an enterprise Feature in 2007. However, using InfoPath Workflow Forms were available in Standard, because it's an integral feature of Workflows. I haven't verified, but I believe that WSSv3 also supported them)